# CSS - disable font:inherit

Tags: html, css

I wonder how to disable `font:inherit` since I get it in the Ionic from the global css, and I need to disable it since it is getting in the way of rendering text with styles when I use `ng-bind-html`, since it is giving classes to the `i` tags or `bold` tags in the text that I am getting.
I have tried in the css with:

```
p {
  all: revert;
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: You're going to have to override it in your own CSS with the font you want.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: A per-element `<span>` override using `<element><span style="font-family: specific, generic;">Your Text</span></element>` works nicely in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your own style sheet you'll need to add an override specifying your own css rule,

example:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-override-technique/

```
p {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}
```

You would need to override inside your own stytle sheet for the i and bold tags but that's quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be suggesting using an `!important` to do this as it could cause more issues for you later on down the road, an important should be the last case scenario.

I would suggest just making the part of your css that sets the global font family a little more specific than what is declaring the font property.

So for example, if you `font:` property is being declared on `<p>` tags do something like this:

```
p {
  font: inherit;
}

body p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```

That way you don't need to potentially override the font family with more `!important`s.